# Get the user's sign-up sequence number in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to display a user by their sign-up order number.  To give a specific example, I want to display "You are user 7 of 7,182".  I am easily able to get the 7,182( the total number of users reactively).  What I can't figure out is how to publish only the sign up order number of the individual user.

Comment: Surely you are saving each user with an incrementing ID? Just use that?

Comment: Yo can look at their createdate. something like select count(*) from (select createdate from user where createdate <= user's createdate)

Comment: @SameerNaik Without proper indexation that would eventually cripple the server wouldn't it?

Comment: @Kyll This value can be computed once and stored. It is not going to change again.

Comment: @SameerNaik Excluding time travelers I suppose you are right. Then maybe using an incremental field on creation would be enough.

Comment: Yes, but it has to be done at user creation time. SQL approach works if the counter was not created when user was created.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a counter collection via an [auto incrementing sequence field](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) to generate a counter to be stored as a property for each User record.

For example, you could create a counter collection and get the last sequence by using:

```
Counters.findAndModify({
  query: {type: "user"},
  update: {$inc: {seq: 1}},
  new: true,
  upsert: true
}).seq;
```

You could then assign the resulting sequence to a property on a newly-created User. This approach requires a package that includes findAndModify (https://github.com/fongandrew/meteor-find-and-modify).

Of course, this solution would only apply to newly-created users unless you manually assign all the existing users a counter.

If you assigned the sequence result to a property on your user such as `userNumber`, then you could just publish that property.